# WP / WC calling add_action "init" from inside another function

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem with a plugin and WooCommerce.

So I have a plugin with an options page, and a custom checkbox on it.

When this checkbox is activated, I want to hide/remove the default WooCommerce related product container.

I can remove this container if I just add this code:

```
    add_action( 'init', 'add_action_function');

    function add_action_function(){
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20);
    }
```

But the problem is that I need to call this function from inside another  "add_filter" function.

In the moment I have something like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'add_filter_function' );

function add_filter_function () {

    // Get the plugin option
    $active = get_option( 'prfx_active', 'no');

    // If option value is "yes", remove the related products container
    if ($active = 'yes') {

        // I think this add_action call is wrong
        add_action( 'init', 'add_action_function');

        function add_action_function(){
           remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20);
        }

    }//END if $active = yes

  // Do some other stuff here

}//END add_filter_function
```

But when I change the option in the admin-settings, nothing changes. So I think the "init" hook is not right here.

I cant find the right hook to make this work. What hook must I use when I want it to fire when the plugin options get updated?

Thanks in advanced,
Mo

---

Thanks to Danijel and his answers.

I dont know why I didnt think of it this way.
Maybe this was to much "action" for me on that late evening ;)

I now placed the "add_action" outside of the "add_filter" function and just do the conditional-check there.

This is working:

```
            add_action( 'init', 'hide_related');
            function hide_related () {

                if ( get_option( 'prfx_active', 'no' ) == 'yes' ) {
                    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20);
                }

            };

add_filter( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'add_filter_function' );
function add_filter_function () {
    ...
```

Comment: Hi, there is a specific [wordpress site in stackexchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/), you may get an answer a little faster in there :)

Comment: Oh, thanks Armfoot for that tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im quite certain that WP `init` action is fired before `woocommerce_after_single_product_summary` filter, and also `if ( $active = 'yes'  { ...` expression will always be evaluated as `true` ( use `==` ). Try with this simple example:

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    if ( get_option( 'prfx_active', 'no' ) == 'yes' )
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much Danijel! It is working with that code, I updated my original post/question.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving your `add_action_funciton` outside of `add_filter_function`

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'add_filter_function' );
function add_action_function(){
   remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20);
}

function add_filter_function () {
    // Get the plugin option
    $active = get_option( 'prfx_active', 'no');
    // If option value is "yes", remove the related products container
    if ($active = 'yes') {
        // I think this add_action call is wrong
        add_action( 'init', 'add_action_function');
    }//END if $active = yes
  // Do some other stuff here
}//END add_filter_function
```